# Picking data from the database with ajax and saving the last one picked

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

I'm picking a random row every 10 seconds from my `mysql` table using ajax.

The problem is I want to prevent picking the same rows twice (one by one). I can use sessions, to keep the last picked row id, but I want it to be server-side.

I can also send the update query to the database with the last picking unix time, but I want to prevent servers overloads and I care about the performance... so this idea isn't that nice.

As you can have some more experience related to the performance, I would like to get some ideas from you, regarding the above problem. Thank you guys in advance.

// I've placed the `codeigniter` tag, because this thing may be important for this problem.

Comment: From the page load, every 10 second there is picked a random row, and it will repeat the ajax request until user will close the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think storing the last selected record id in the user session on the server side is the best solution. In this way you can get the last selected ID for that user and exclude it from your query.

If you are planning to create an extra database table holding the last selected id, keep in mind that your site may have more than one concurrent visitor, so you'll have to store the last selected ID for each visitor, assuming the ID must not be unique.

If each visitor must see the same ID at the same time, the idea in the previous paragraph could be a possible solution, or even add a boolean field to the table that needs to be queried and set it to true for the current record and false for all the other ones. You will have to make use of the timestamp in your queries to make sure you only return one new unique record different from the last one at each 10 second interval.